# how to show user sender name when contact form submitted

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, form-submit

I want to show username inside the  div alert-success when user submitting the contact form. How can I do it, can you help me please?
I have index.php page and mailer.php
   =====index.php=====

```
<form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="contact-form">    
   <?php    
     if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
      if ($_GET['success'] == 1) {          
    echo "<div class=\"alert-success success\">Thank you! Your 
     message has been sent.</div>";         
    }else{
    echo "<div class=\"alert-danger error\">Sorry! Something went 
    wrong, please try again.</div>";
        }       
    }       
?>
```

[image: mailer.php]

Comment: When you state "username", (a) do users actually sign into your site, or (b) do you simply want to display the person's name, as input into your form?

Comment: why is the rest of the code as an image? you should have been posting real code instead, just as you did above it

Comment: Hi. Just i want to display the person's name as input into the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use `session`
at the top of action script, call

```
<?php 
/* mailler.php */
session_start();

//Get the form fields, remove html tags and whitespace
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
//... code after
```

your action code like this

```
 /* mailler.php */
 // ....code before
 // Send email
 mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);

 //add this code
 $_SESSION['success'] = ['state'=> 1, 'name'=> $name];

 //Redirect to the index.html page with form fragment
 header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php#form');
 exit();
```

And your form contact like this

```
<form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="contact-form">    
 <?php    
   if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
     if ($_SESSION['success']['state'] == 1) {          
      echo "<div class=\"alert-success success\">Thank you ". $_SESSION['success']['name'] ."! Your 
       message has been sent.</div>";         
     }else{
        echo "<div class=\"alert-danger error\">Sorry! Something went 
        wrong, please try again.</div>";
    }
    unset($_SESSION['success']);         
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but doesn't work. I can't see alert message. when I submit the form just I see clear contact form area again so invisible echo message